# How to derive a data from join table table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 3 table as following.
Now starting from Sell_Table how can i derive the Country_Cod?
How can i use the Prod_Table as a bridge between the other two tables?

```
select count(Sell_Table.id), Country_Cod, avg(Sell_Table.Ammount)
from sell_table
left join ?
group by Country_Cod
```

Thanks

```
1)Country table
+--- -+-------------+
| id  | Country_Cod |
+---- +-------------+
| 101 | IT          |
| 102 | US          |
| 103 | GB          |
| 104 | TR          |
+-----+-------------+
```

```
2) Prod_Table
+-----+------------+---------+
| id  | Country_id | Sell__id|
+---- +------------+---------+
| 101 |101         | 101     |
| 102 |102         |         |
| 103 |102         | 102     |
| 104 |103         |         |
+-----+------------+---------+
```

```
3) Sell_Table
+-----+------------+----------+
| id  | Prod_id    | Amount   |
+---- +------------+----------+
| 101 |101         | 100      |
| 102 |103         | 200      |
| 103 |107         | 300      |
| 104 |110         | 400      |
+-----+------------+----------+
```

Comment: 'I have 3 table as following' - You only show one.. Please add expected output as well as all tables.

Comment: You dont have a country name, you only have a short code for a country! Is that what you wanted to find?

Comment: Your `Prod_Table.Country_id` is 4 chars and does not match your `Country.id` which is 3 chars

Comment: Also your `Prod_Table.Sell_Id` does not match your `Sell_Table.id`

Comment: `Sell_Table.Ammount` is spelt wrongly. you have called that column `Amout` in the schema

Comment: You are not agregating any column but you are grouping? Not sure what you expect to do with the result of a query like that as it would basically be nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want two joins:

```
select s.id, c.country_code, s.amount
from sell s
inner join prod p on p.id = s.prod_id
inner join country c on c.id = p.country_id
```

Comment: Can I transform this  2 joins in one sub query?

Comment: @Dripet84: that's surely possible, but what don't you like about this query?

Comment: This work, i just wanted to know how can it be in subquery cause its a little slow